# Parse XML tags in PHP

Tags: php, xml, wsdl

I am getting response from WSDL something like this:

```
string(221) : "RMT_TOKEN_ACKTHAMORTEST91001e659a4f4-8fb1-4fe1-95dd-62da8d4c3fb401"
```

Documentation states that, response should be,

```
<TRX_MESSAGE>
<MESSAGE>
<MESSAGE_ID>RMT_TOKEN_ACK</MESSAGE_ID>
<USR_NAME>THAMORTEST</USR_NAME>
<AGENT_CODE>91001</AGENT_CODE>
<TOKEN>e659a4f4-8fb1-4fe1-95dd-62da8d4c3fb4</TOKEN>
<RESP_CODE>01</RESP_CODE>
</MESSAGE>
</TRX_MESSAGE>
```

When I counted original response characters, I found it's 221. But, I can not see entire string in my response. You can see there is no XML tags in my result string. How to get token from this?

I know, it's quite confusing. Let me know, if you need any kind of information. thanks.

Comment: looks like a concat of the message_id, usr_name, agent_code, token, and resp_code to me ... i.e. the XML <message> stripped of tags.

Comment: You're not passing your response through `strip_tags()` are you?

Comment: try var_dump($response) where $response is what you get from wsdl. Browser will treat that string as html and will not show tags.

Comment: I posted answer for this. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
$token_string = $result->getTokenReturn;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$token_string = "RMT_TOKEN_ACKTHAMORTEST91001e659a4f4-8fb1-4fe1-95dd-62da8d4c3fb401"
```

**PHP**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($token_string);
$tokens = $dom->getElementsByTagName('TOKEN');
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    echo $token->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Required OUTPUT (Token only)**:

```
e659a4f4-8fb1-4fe1-95dd-62da8d4c3fb4
```